# Windows 7 stuck in "Starting Windows" many times

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

On a friend's quite old PC, which was running Windows XP, he said to me that sometimes it was very slow and needed multiple reboots, so I thought there was a problem with the HDD. I found 1 bad sector, I installed Windows 7 Ultimate and on the first reboot it stuck in "Starting Windows" screen, freezing with the Windows flag showing. We tried to boot it a few times, cutting the power, and after 5-6 tries it booted on Windows. So, I was sure it was the HDD and told him to buy a new one.

New disk, new installation of Windows 7 Ultimate, all updates done and on the 2nd reboot it stuck again in "Starting Windows", the same thing. After 5-6 power cuts it then boots.

So, it's not the HDD. Is it a driver? But if it's a driver, why does it boot after some tries? Is it a hardware error? It never happened before I installed Windows 7. So is it an incompatibility with Windows 7 and the old PC?

I don't know what to do now.

Comment: is your legacy boot up option in bios disabled?

Answer (score 0):

To rule out the HDD as the cause of the issue, make a boot USB device (2 GB or larger) for another OS, e.g. [Ubuntu Linux](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

If the PC runs well, each time you boot from the USB drive, you could then install Linux dual-boot on the PC -- if *that* works, then the cause is probably not an HDD issue.

[Also check the CMOS/clock battery, which, if weak or dead, might cause the issue.](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/11/618460171318429760/)

BTW, your friend might prefer Linux to Windows XP and 7, both of which Microsoft has deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

You can try these, if it's a software error this might work!

Try Running 'Startup Repair' from a Windows recovery disc.

If it fails, open command prompt in the recovery disc. Try these command's there:

bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd

BTW also try changing from ACHI to IDE in your motherboard bios settings.

Comment: These commands cannot solve the author's described problem